# Hide flex items if space if enough space not available

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am making a JIRA timeline chart and I am showing some information related to epics in progress. If an epic spans across multiple releases, the timeline bar has enough space to show information. But if an Epic only spans one release, the space is too limited to show all the information as shown below(Notice how "Open" is getting chopped off):

[image: Improper space]

If the space is limited, I want to show all details except for the JIRA ticket status like this. Basically, I want to hide the status when space is limited (Note: the width of the accordion is being controlled by the grid column templates so I can't use static width)

[image]

Below is some sample code

```css
.accordion {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.accordion-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.epic-summary {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.timeline-bar {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.timeline-bar>div {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <div class="timeline-bar">
      <div>JIRA-1234</div>
      <div><img alt="Url  Icon" width="25" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/url-17-695478.png?f=webp&amp;w=256" srcset="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/url-17-695478.png?f=webp&amp;w=256 1x, https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/url-17-695478.png?f=webp&amp;w=512 2x"></div>
      <div class="epic-summary">EPIC: This is some description</div>
      <div>In progress</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="accordion-toggle">
    <img src="   https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2985/2985150.png " width="25" height="25">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `min-width` or `overflow` so that the elements are shrinking.

```css
.accordion {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: min(600px, 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.accordion-content {
  flex: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.timeline-bar {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.timeline-bar>div {
  padding: 0 5px;
  flex: none;
}

.timeline-bar>.epic-summary{
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <div class="timeline-bar">
      <div>JIRA-1234</div>
      <div><img alt="Url  Icon" width="25" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/url-17-695478.png?f=webp&amp;w=256" srcset="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/url-17-695478.png?f=webp&amp;w=256 1x, https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/url-17-695478.png?f=webp&amp;w=512 2x"></div>
      <div class="epic-summary">EPIC: This is some description</div>
      <div>In progress</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="accordion-toggle">
    <img src="   https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2985/2985150.png " width="25" height="25">
  </div>
</div>
```